# Repository pattern implementation with ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

In my project, I trying to implement repository pattern and unit of work. 
I found some web site to describe how to implement it such as:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688929/Repository-Pattern-and-Unit-of

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/561584/Repository-Pattern-with-Entity-Framework-using

I was wondering, why is not generic Unit of Work and Repositories Framework? then try several search on internet and I found it,

http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

This framework is first code but my project is model first therefore is not work correctly?

Could you please suggest me model first framework like this?

My project is a internet web site with one database, If there is plausible reason I can change model first approach to code first approach.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Entity Framework is already a repository pattern so you do not need to wrap it up in another.

Comment: @coolblue2000 thanks for your response, but if EF is already repo pattern, why developed http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/ for EF6?

Comment: No idea. EF6 is also Mockable so there is no need to wrap it up at all. The entities themselves are the repositories (in the repository pattern), these have calls to update, get and save data.

Comment: coolblue2000, One of the primary reasons for implementing the repository pattern is to minimize the surface area of your our ORM technology e.g. EF, nHibernate etc. Compartmentalization of where your CRUD is happening in your application, so instead of having CRUD happening throughout your presentation layer you have them the repository layer, where they can also reused as well. This also provides abstraction, which in return if you were to ever switch ORM technologies, you would be mitigating how much refactoring you would need to do. Read up on this for many more reasons for this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

We've abstracted all the interfaces in our latest release into Repository.Pattern project https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Source/Repository.Pattern, in plans to implement nHibernate provider. You are more than welcome to start implementing these interfaces, based on bandwidth at the moment, I cannot commit to any dates as of yet.